# displaying json output properly in a table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an ajax function which sends a get request to an api and retrieves some JSON, which I am displaying in a table. This is what I have tried-

```
<script>




function getInfo() {


     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://example.com/",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         crossDomain: true,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

            $("table.mytable").append("<tr><td>First Name</td><td>" + data[i].firstname + "</td></tr><tr><td>Last Name</td><td>" + data[i].lastname + 
            "</td></tr><tr><td>Queues</td><td>" + 
             data[i].skills +  "</td></tr>"  );
          }


             alert("success");
         },

         error: function (jqXHR, status) {
             // error handler
             console.log(jqXHR);
             alert('fail' + status.code);
         }
      });
   }


</script>
```

However, the output on the html page looks like this-

First Name  John
Last Name   Smith
Skills          Maths
First Name  Jane
Last Name   Smith
Skills          Maths

I would like the First Name, Last Name and Skills headers to be across the table, with the data underneath. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Yeah, try to think logical? Do you know how to make an HTML table!?

Comment: Evidently not, but I do have some manners

Comment: Suggest: First build up a hardcoded HTML table with dummy data inside, if you like the result, generalize it and use JavaScript to insert dynamic data into it. I bet you have syntax error in HTML.

Comment: Each `td` is the start of a new column, so, your first row should be hardcoded to be the headers, then just append your `data` info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace you for loop with this:

```
$("table.mytable").html("<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Queues</th></tr>"  );

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
   $("table.mytable").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].firstname + "</td><td>Last Name</td><td>" + data[i].lastname + "</td><td>" + data[i].skills +  "</td></tr>"  );
}
```

The whole ajax should look like this:

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://example.com/",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         crossDomain: true,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

            $("table.mytable").html("<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Queues</th></tr>"  );

    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
       $("table.mytable").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].firstname + "</td><td>Last Name</td><td>" + data[i].lastname + "</td><td>" + data[i].skills +  "</td></tr>"  );
    }


             alert("success");
         },

         error: function (jqXHR, status) {
             // error handler
             console.log(jqXHR);
             alert('fail' + status.code);
         }
      });
```